# Why does the 737 Original have an explicit hydraulic-quantity indicator for only the A hydraulic system?

Tags: boeing-737, hydraulic-system, cockpit-alerts, gauge

The 737 (Original, Classic, NG, and MAX) has two primary hydraulic systems (A and B),<sup>1</sup> which provide power to the aircraft’s flight controls and other aircraft components (like the wheelbrakes, landing-gear extension/retraction, and nosewheel steering).

On all 737s, the cockpit instrument panels have gauges which provide a readout of the pressure available in both of the primary hydraulic systems.<sup>2</sup>  Hydraulic *quantity*, however, is a different matter; on the 737 Original, the cockpit instrumentation features a quantity gauge only for the A hydraulic system, with the B system having to make do with a mere low-quantity warning light (the same type of indicator as with the standby hydraulic system, although on a different one of the instrument panels):

[image: ye originale hydraulickes]

(Diagram originally by the [National Transportation Safety Board](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR0101.pdf), page 11 [page 29 of the PDF]; cropped and imageified by me.)

In contrast, the later 737 Classic has quantity gauges for each of the two primary hydraulic systems:

[image: ye classicke hydraulickes]

(Diagram originally by the [National Transportation Safety Board](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR9901.pdf), page 17 [page 41 of the PDF]; cropped and imageified by me.)

Why doesn’t the Original have quantity gauges for both main hydraulic systems, rather than just for the A system?

---

<sup>1</sup>: A third, standby system is unpressurised in normal flight, but can be activated by the flightcrew (or, in a few critical situations, automatically) in the event of a primary hydraulic failure; the 737 also has manual-reversion capability for the ailerons and elevators in the event of a complete hydraulic failure, one of only a few jetliners to still include this capability.

<sup>2</sup>: The standby hydraulic system, which is normally unpressurised anyways, merely has a warning light that comes on if the pressure within an active standby system falls too low.

Comment: You're still asking a lot of theoretical questions. I'd like to see questions from you like "how do I license a US-registered airplane in Korea" or "what's the best way to ferry a Cessna across the Pacific" or "can I replace my own alternator or must the FBO do it" or "how do I get this bolt off (pic)" or "how open are Russian authorities to fly-ins by South Koreans?"  :) :) :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Bit hard to ask non-theoretical questions when I'm not a pilot (nor likely to ever be one) or an aircraft mechanic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Your question*: **Why doesn’t the Original have quantity gauges for both main hydraulic systems, rather than just for the A system?**

On the B737 100/200 airplanes the system ***B*** hydraulic reservoir is filled from the system ***A*** reservoir.  So, when the system ***A*** gauge displays a normal quantity the system ***B*** reservoir quantity would also be normal (separate ***B*** quantity gauge not required).

If the ***B*** hydraulic reservoir "low quantity" warning light illuminated then the ***A*** hydraulic reservoir would be at a level of about 1.8 gals (balance line between the ***A*** & ***B*** reservoirs leaves fluid in the ***A*** reservoir if only the ***B*** system leaks) and its quantity gauge would indicate so. (and there would be a low quantity or total depletion of the ***B*** system reservoir also)

B737-300 airplanes and later models have a differently designed hydraulic system in this regard.

Comment: Wouldn't interconnecting the A and B hydraulic reservoirs defeat the purpose (redundancy) of having two hydraulic systems in the first place (by allowing fluid from one system to be lost through a breach in the other)?

Comment: @Sean - if the B system has a leak, not all of the fluid will drain from the A reservoir because of where the balance line is between the A & B reservoirs (once the fluid in the A reservoir gets to a level below the balance line [about 1.8 gal remaining] the B leak no longer drains fluid from the A reservoir ). Also, if the A system leaks the B system quantity remains intact.